# asset-url not generating correct url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sass

I seem to have a strange error where my url for assets (via AWS bucket) is not being generated correctly. For whatever reason my ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY'] is not being read.

Production

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

I have set the ENV to the correct value (ie) my bucket name but if i use this for example

```
background-image: asset-url('toggle-open.png') left top no-repeat;
```

The url generated is

```
http://.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/toggle-open-f60c19a2e6d5b3757da06370fc8d0c57.png
```

Why would this not generate

```
http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/toggle-open-f60c19a2e6d5b3757da06370fc8d0c57.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would just share what i done to get this working.

Normally I would run

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

before deploying to heroku.. However on this occasion i cleared my tmp/cache and my public/assets and committed to git hub repo, and then ran

```
git push heroku master
```

at which point my assets where precompiled upon deployment and the image paths where correct